# A data breach on a site exposed your password message sent by chrome on my login form

Tags: php

I made a login form, an authenticated user is redirected to their home page. But, along with redirection chrome sent me this [image: This is the message sent by chrome]

I know nothing about the warning. My code is:

```
     /**
     * Go Login, login button is clicked
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function goLoginAction()
    {
        $user = new User($_POST);

        if ($user->verifyPassword()) {
            $user = User::findByUsername($user->username);

            Auth::login($user);

            $this->redirect("/$user->username/home/");
        } 

        $this->redirect('/');

    }
```

go-login is the action of the form. So, $_POST is sent to go-login. 
verifyPassword is the function to verify password:

```
     /**
     * Verify password
     * 
     * @return true if password is correct, false otherwise
     */
    public function verifyPassword()
    {
        $users = static::findByUsername($this->username);
        if (password_verify($this->password, $users->password)) {
            return true;            
        }
        return false;
    }
```

findByUsername is the function to return the object user by username. And, Auth class in the go-login function creates the session:

```
     /**
     * Login controller
     * Set session after login
     * 
     * @param object $user 
     * @return void
     */
    public static function login($user)
    {
        session_regenerate_id();

        $_SESSION['id'] = $user->id;
    }
```

Every answer would be appreciated. And please let me know the other security tips as well. Thank you!!

Comment: https://www.welivesecurity.com/2019/12/12/chrome-warnings-password-stolen/

Comment: This is a new Chrome feature that checks your passwords against past breaches. It's nothing to do with your code.

Comment: @anyber Then is it showing that my password is weak?

Comment: @BiploveLamichhane it's saying that the username/password you used has been compromised somewhere else and google knows about it. It's not a matter of the password being weak or strong, but that it's been exposed in the past. Google is just trying to help you stay secure.

Comment: @FunkyMonk91 Oh!!! I got it.. Thank you !!!

Comment: @FunkyMonk91 How to avoid this message

Comment: @StackKiddy You can simply use difficult passwords to avoid the message. This error is shown when your password is simple and can be bruteforced. That means, password like *hello*,  *stackkiddy*, *biplove*. Just google how to secure password, there will be thousands of blogs on the topic.

Comment: Thanks....I will set difficult passwords

Comment: Yes absolutely. But, during development process you can simply ignore that message. Stay safe. Happy code.

Comment: This happens whenever I use username/password like test/test on localhost. Which is quite silly of Chrome.

Comment: Yes. Kind of a silly. But, might be very important for non developer people with no knowledge of bruteforce attacks.

Comment: Though it is not related to the code, but I would also recommend adding strong password mechanism on the website like having min 6 alphanumeric characters, 1 capital letter, 1 special character, etc. This will make sure user will not enter weak or normal passwords on the website making chrome think that user is not using normal password.

Comment: Yes... you are right.. but for development its kind of annoying to set the strong password pattern...

Comment: More importantly, don't use a password that you've used on other sites.

Answer (score 6):

**I see the comments have cleared your doubts well, but just in case here is a small conclusion for newcomers.**

### TL:DR

This is a recently introduced feature to Google Chrome. If, in the past the submitted combination of the provided username/email-password pair was breached, Chrome will try to warn the user that maybe he/she would be better off using something more strong. It has nothing to do with code, which means that you are the one responsible for your users' security.

### External links to read about this topic.

1. [This was asked and answered on Google Chrome Help community.](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/23534509?hl=en&msgid=23534509)
2. If you are interested in what makes a strong password and how it is all connected to cryptography, consider checking out the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength), it is pretty well written.

Comment: Does that mean that google chrome sends all my passwords from all pages somewhere to server where it checks if it is one of breached ones and then do who know what with it ?

Comment: @JiroMatchonson The add-on is [allegedly](https://security.googleblog.com/2019/02/protect-your-accounts-from-data.html) “designed…to never reveal this personal information to Google”; it _checks_ them offline, AFAICT, **but**, when it _finds_ a match, it does report back to Google about it- though allegedly using some closed-source “privacy-preserving technologies” to reduce the amount of the user's data leaked thereby.