# A window "Check your passwords" after axios request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, axios

After registering on the site, such a window pops up.

"Check your passwords. A data breach on a site exposed your password..."

Requests on server look like this:

```
import * as axios from 'axios'

const instance = axios.create({
    withCredentials: true,
    baseURL: 'api',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
})

export const API = {
    signAPI : {
        signUp: (email, password, name, surname, username) => {
            return instance.post(`users/sign`, {email, password, name, surname, username})
                .then(response => {
                    return response
                })
        },
}
```

Perhaps I should pass some additional headers?

Comment: this is something outside your code but is browser/os dependent. Try to use a stronger password to get rid of that. The password you are using has been leaked and the browser is warning you it is not safe at all

Comment: yes, you are right. Password must contain at least 8 characters

Comment: Read this to learn about this feature: https://security.googleblog.com/2019/12/better-password-protections-in-chrome.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A data breach on a site exposed your password message sent by chrome on my login form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59410675/a-data-breach-on-a-site-exposed-your-password-message-sent-by-chrome-on-my-login)